# JAVA - For loop and If else statement

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure out what's wrong with this answer to the question. Really need help! Any help is appreciated! Thanks

*Question*

- you can enter two ints(a and b), and
- the program will print from number a to number b if `a<b`.
- If `a>b`, the program will print from b to a.
- If `b is the same as a`, the program will ask the user to enter another number b until it is not equal to a.

  ```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a: ");
  int a = sc.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter b: ");
  int b = sc.nextInt();

  if(a > b) {
      for(int i = b; b >= a; b--) {
          System.out.println(b);
      }
  } else if (a < b) {
      for(int i = a; a <= b; a++) {
          System.out.println(i);
      }
  } else {
      System.out.println("Enter another number b: ");
      int numberb = sc.nextInt();
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made a few corrections to your current attempt, which was not far off from being functional.  First, I use a loop to keep prompting the user to input a `b` number until `a` does not equal `b`.  With distinct `a` and `b` in hand, I then do a single loop to print out the range of numbers from smallest to greatest, inclusive on both ends.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a: ");
int a = sc.nextInt();
int b;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter b: ");
    b = sc.nextInt();
} while (b == a);

for (int i=Math.min(a, b); i <= Math.max(a,b); ++i) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: `while(true)` and `break` is not very 'good-practice', `do/while` is made for :)

Comment: @azro Refactored, thanks, and you just eliminated one line of unnecessary code.  Now let's think of a way to replace the whole thing with a one-line lambda ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To allow the user to enter a `b` until it's different of `a` you can use a `do while loop`

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a: ");
int a = sc.nextInt();
int b = 0;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter b: ");
    b = sc.nextInt();
} while (a == b);
```

Then to print you can simply do :

```
for (int i=Math.min(a, b); i <= Math.max(a,b); ++i) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Or correct your code :

```
 if (a > b) {
    for (int i = b; i <= a; i++) {   // i is the index to change
        System.out.println(i);       // use i
    }
} else if (a < b) {
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {   // i is the index to change
        System.out.println(i);       // use i
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop iteration is wrong. For your third condition I have made few changes. Change your code:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        test t = new test();
        System.out.println("Enter a: ");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter b: ");
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        if(a==b) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Both are same enter again");
                b = sc.nextInt();
            }while(a==b);
            t.loop(a, b);
        }else {
            t.loop(a,b);
        }
    }
    void loop(int a, int b) {
        if(a > b) {
            for(int i = b; i <= a; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        } else if (a < b) {
            for(int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```